# Check if someone is connect on a Socket Channel on Laravel Controller

Tags: sockets, websocket, socket.io

I've a structure like this:

Socket server-side:

```
    var fs = require('fs');
    var pkey = fs.readFileSync('../../../../etc/letsencrypt/privkey.pem');
    var pcert = fs.readFileSync('../../../../etc/letsencrypt/cert.pem')
    var options = {
        key: pkey,
        cert: pcert,
        requestCert: false,
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    };
    var app = require('https').createServer(options);
    var io = require('socket.io')(app);
    var Redis = require('ioredis');
    var redis = new Redis();
    app.listen(8443, function () {
        console.log('Server is running!');
    });

    redis.subscribe('resumo');

    redis.on('message',function(channel,message){
        console.log(channel, message);
        message=JSON.parse(message);

        console.log(channel+':'+message.event, message);
        io.emit()
    });

    function handler(req, res) {
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end('');
    }

    var totalUsers = 0;

    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        totalUsers++;
        console.log('a user connected');
        io.emit('users', totalUsers);
        socket.on('disconnect', function(){
            totalUsers--;
            io.emit('users', totalUsers);
            console.log('user disconnected');
        });
        socket.on('exit', function(channel){
            var teste = socket.eventNames();
            console.log('desconectado de: '+teste);
        });
        socket.on('entrar', function(channel){
            socket.join(channel);
            console.log('conectado em: '+channel);
        });
    });
    redis.psubscribe('*', function (err, count) {
        //
    });
    redis.on('pmessage', function (subscribed, channel, message) {
        io.emit(channel, message);
    });
```

Client-side:

```
    var socket = io.connect('https://mywebsite.com:8443/');
    socket.on('u_123', function (data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        window[data['function']](data);
    });
```

And i publish on channels like this:

```
    Redis::publish('u_123', json_encode([
        'data' => [somedata]
    ]));
```

I need to check if there is someone connected on this channel 'u_123' on the laravel controller, is this possible? How could i do this? I'm really bad on the javascript part so i'm having a lot of difficulty with this...

Answer (score 0):

according to socket.IO documentation

> Each Socket in Socket.IO is identified by a random, unguessable, unique identifier Socket#id. For your convenience, each socket automatically joins a room identified by this id.

So you can store these ids in an array on the `connection` event, and on `exit` you can remove it from the list.

Comment: Just guessing is this is the best way to do this, also, i'm not sure if this will work if the user close the navigator...

Comment: Your socket on the node.js side will receive a "disconnect" event when the browser closes the connection, which you can then react to.
Feel free to use db for the better solution, but youd have to do sth Like how I explained. :)

Comment: Thanks, i think it will solve my problem, i'll save the user information on the redis cache...

Comment: you can close the topic if this helped you solve the issue. Let me know if you need more help.